# Is there a library for Visual C++ that renders math formulas?

Tags: math, visual-c++, mathml, formulas

I've been looking all over, but I can't find anything free that will let me simply display math formulas on a window. I found one for Visual C++.net, but no APIs. Are there any out there?

Comment: You might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_markup The issue is the form of your formula. If you need to parse and display, that is hard. If you just need to display, look at any of the open source LaTex libraries.

Comment: "I found one for Visual C++.net, but no APIs": so what wast that if it was not an API?

Answer (score 2):

What format are the Math formulas in?

My first impulse would be to try and find a LaTeX library for C++ which will let you render out LaTeX to an image. That way you could display most basic formulas, but the formulas would have to be in the LaTeX format.

Answer (score 1):

Try ReforMath (http://reformath.webnode.com). Runs under both Windows and Linux. It is unfinished though, but can render a number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

What a great question!   Yes, there is now: [latexpp](https://github.com/goldsborough/latexpp).

You'll have to install VS 2017 Community first with the minimal amount of C++ features checked (so it doesn't take *all* day).

Then you install Boost using the [binary (try the latest)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/).

But you still have to build boost.  By using the VS > Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt.  CD to your boost directory and run `.\bootstrap.bat`, then `.\bjam.exe`.  This *will* take all day.

Good news is it seems to be working so far on Windows 7, 64-bit with VS 2017 community and the latest boost 1.6.x.

The Latex library has other requirements, and I still haven't tried it but will post my notes here if any hickups.

---

Make sure all your directories are short, such as `C:\VisualStudio2017`.  However, boost will then fail if you use your regular windows command prompt unless you do the `vcvarsall.bat` trick.  The VS Command Prompt does that for you, so that boost can find your MSVC stuff.  Boost would still probably fail if you used the default directory and didn't use the VS command prompt.

So, again, my boost is in `C:\boost_{blah version}` which you should shorten to `C:\boost` assuming you'll only use one version of boost.

One reason is that if you have to add the respective `/bin` directories to your system `Path`, then you won't fail by maxing out the length of `Path` value (yes, it has a max length).  Also stuff is easy to find and especially from the command line so you can `cd` quickly there.  If you don't want everything in `C:\` then make a `C:\__TOOLS` or something short.

---

I will post my notes here when I've gotten LaTeX rendered.

### Notes

- When building boost with bjam, if it seemingly hangs for more than 10 mins on one item, then hit `ctrl-C` at the command line once.  This seems to unhang it without canceling the install.
- TODO